# Short Ruby Case Statement using include? Will Not Work

Tags: ruby, case

I have the following code with a small bug in it, the case statement returns the value "other" even though the first "when" statement evaluates true and should return "boats".

I've been been looking at this for ages, must be something small.

```
CATEGORY_CLASSES = {:boats  => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              :houses => [7, 8, 9, 10],
              :other  => [11,12,13,14,15,16]
             }

category_id = 1

category = case category_id
  when CATEGORY_CLASSES[:boats].include?(category_id); "boats"
  when CATEGORY_CLASSES[:houses].include?(category_id); "houses"
  else "other"
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `:cars` label in your hash. So it's impossible to return "boats"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `case` statement is usually just a shorthand for an `if` statement. Yours can be rewritten as:

```
if CATEGORY_CLASSES[:boats].include?(category_id) === category_id
  category = "boats"
elsif CATEGORY_CLASSES[:houses].include?(category_id) === category_id
  category = "houses"
else
  category = "other"
end
```

When you look at it in this form, you should see the problem clearly; while `include?` returns a boolean, you're comparing it against an integer value.

Comment: Actually `case` uses `===`, not `==`, but in this case the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @sepp2k my bad, that's what I meant to write.

Answer (score 57):

You can expand array in **when** statement as follows:

```
category = case category_id
  when *CATEGORY_CLASSES[:boats]; "boats"
  when *CATEGORY_CLASSES[:houses]; "houses"
  else "other"
end
```

Comment: Splat operator is hawt, though this may end up being less efficient than an if statement.

Comment: I prefer this nice syntax to the accepted answer. Also regarding @MikeJ comment a benchmark would be nice.

Comment: Decided to do a benchmark for this. [Apparently](https://pastebin.com/c8CYCVpn) using case with array expansion is 1.5x slower (tested on `ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]`)

Answer (score 7):

<sub>(I'm going to ignore the fact that your hash does not actually contain any of the keys you were checking for and pretend you're checking for keys that are actually in the hash. Hopefully this is the right assumption.)</sub>

You appear to misunderstand what a `case` statement is. It's testing the value of the object of the `case` statement, not merely running a bunch of vaguely related `if`s. The `when`-clauses are all compared with `===` to the object of the `case` statement. So if you write `CATEGORY_CLASSES[:boats].include?(category_id)`, then it either means `if true === category_id` or `if false === category_id` (since `include?` returns either true or false).

What you want is more like `CATEGORIES.find {|k,v| v.include? category_id}.first.to_s`.

Comment: Actually the Ruby case statement has two forms, and one of the is indeed meant to run a bunch of vaguely related ifs. He probably intended to use the other case form, which you get by following the case directly with a when.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda here. like so.

```rb
boats = ->(id) { CATEGORY_CLASSES[:boats].include? id }
houses = ->(id) { CATEGORY_CLASSES[:houses].include? id }

category = case category_id
  when boats; "boats"
  when houses; "houses"
  else "other"
end
```

How does this work? case calls `===` on the left operand. In procs/lambdas, `===` is same as `#call`